# Rails trying to create a user when updating user details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning rails and building an authentication system using guides from around the web and following railscasts tutorials.

I've come to a stand still at the moment and need a bit of assistance if possible.

When ever I try to edit the user profile, I get an error message which tells me that it can't create an account due to fields such as email and username already being taken.

Looking around it seems it's related to how my edit form is being submitted, but I can't solve it!

Any help would be appreciated.

**Users_controller.rb**

```
def edit
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
  redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

**edit.html.erb**
         <%= form_for :user, url: '/users' do |f| %>

```
            <form class="m-t" role="form" action="#">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :name %>
                  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', autocomplete: "off" %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :user_type %>
                  <%= f.select(:user_type, ['Admin', 'Technical', 'Accounts'], {}, { :class => 'form-control' }) %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :email %>
                  <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :telephone %>
                  <%= f.text_field :telephone, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :mobile %>
                  <%= f.text_field :mobile, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :user_name %>
                  <%= f.text_field :user_name, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :password %>
                  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
                  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :company_admin%>
                  <%= f.check_box :company_admin, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :user_admin %>
                  <%= f.check_box :user_admin, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :emergency_contact %>
                  <%= f.check_box :emergency_contact, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary block full-width m-b" %>
                </div>
            </form>

            <% end %>
```

**Rails Log**

```
User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'emailaddress@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."user_name" = 'AUserName' LIMIT 1
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_secure_password

 validates :name, presence: { message: "Please enter your name." }
 validates_uniqueness_of :email, presence: { message: "Please enter your email address." }
 validates_format_of :email, with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]    {2,})\z/i, message: "Please enter a valid email address.", allow_blank: true
 validates :telephone, presence: { message: "Please enter your phone number." }
 validates :mobile, presence: { message: "Please enter your mobile number." }
 validates_uniqueness_of :user_name, presence: { message: "Please enter your user name." }
 validates_confirmation_of :password, presence: { message: "Please enter your password" }, allow_nil: true

 before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }

 def generate_token(column)
  begin
   self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
 end

 def send_password_reset
  generate_token(:password_reset_token)
  self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
  save!
  UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
 end

end
```

Comment: Can you post your model, as it's obviously something to do with your validation.

Comment: Updated the original post with the model too. I wasn't convinced on my validation to start with, so your assumption makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Wait I'm wrong on the validation.  Just spotted it.

```
<%= form_for :user, url: '/users' do |f| %>
```

This won't use the `@user` object, which means rails thinks you're trying to create a user.

Switch it to

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
```

Rails will also infer the correct place to post to so you won't need the url option anymore.

Comment: Excellent! Been having minor troubles with rails and it's always the simple things that I over look! Thanks for the prompt resolution!